# The correct usage of bring vs. take

Tags: word-usage, deictic-verbs

My husband continuously uses *bring* versus *take* incorrectly. For example:

> I will **bring** him to church on Sunday.

The correct form is to say:

> I will **take** him to church on Sunday.

I cannot find this grammar rule in Strunk and White.  Could someone please state the rule?

Answer (score 9):

In English, the use of "bring" vs. "take" seems closely matched with the use of "come" vs. "go".  Related to your example:

> Come to church with me.
>
> Let's go to church together.

These requests are more or less the same, even though they use two different verbs with opposite meaning.

Nevertheless there is an underlying logic. Which verb you choose reflects what **point-of-view** from which you imagine the movement.  If you picture yourself already at the church, then you can use *come*.  If you picture yourself at another location, moving *toward* the church, then you use *go*.

In the same way *bring* feels like you are *coming* with the person to the place you want to **be**.

> Let me bring you to church today.

Otherwise, if you feel like you are moving toward some other location, you *take* the person to the place where you want to **go**.

> Let me take you to church today.

Same meaning, just different points-of-view.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely matches colloquial usage I've seen, which can use both verbs correctly and almost interchangeably.

Comment: I'd argue that you can't _bring_ anybody anywhere. If I'm already at church, I can't bring you there. I can invite you to _come_ to church, but I don't think that means I'm bringing you. If I take you to church, we get in the car together and I drive you there. However, if I were already at church, I could ask somebody else to _bring_ you to church.

Comment: If I have an item, I can take it somewhere but I can't bring it. If I don't have an item, it can be brought to me but not taken to me.

Comment: @JasonSwett I agree it's not logical but nevertheless it's perfectly natural English.  And, yes, an item can be taken to me (by someone else), that's also perfectly natural English, as imagined from that person's perspective.

Answer (score 4):

> [You ask people to bring things to the place you are, and you take things to the place you are going](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/bring-versus-take)

So you are correct

> You *take* him to church on Sunday.

On the other hand

> [Bring
>
>   Bring describes the movement of something toward a specified location](http://blog.dictionary.com/bring-vs-take/)
>
> [Take
>
>   Take, on the other hand, generally describes the movement of something away from a location.](http://blog.dictionary.com/bring-vs-take/)

Though on other occasions possibly

> [dragged kicking and screaming](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/drag-someone-kicking-and-screaming)
>   *to make someone do something that they do not want to do*

might come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your husband's sentence would be correct IF he said it while he was at the church. Otherwise, your version would be correct.

There is a subtlety when we talk about bringing something with us, because we are always with ourselves. So, for example, it would be quite correct to say "I will bring the candles [assumed - with me when I come] to church on Sunday".

Comment: +1 So are you in fact saying that we would normally expect *take* but that OP's husband usage is actually correct? It might be good to put that in your answer!

Comment: I don't think so. Someone _else_ could bring the husband's friend to church but the husband himself could not bring someone to church if he was already there. All he could do is invite or summon them. Not bring.