# So we say, "It's starting to rain, let's bring the washing in" or "....let's take the washing in"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

ok, so

> **[hang something ↔ out](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hang-out)** to hang clothes outside in order to dry them
>
> *My job was to hang out the washing.*
>
> *Hang the wet things out to dry.*

But if it's starting to rain, then we say:

"*It's starting to rain, let's bring the washing in*" or "*It's starting to rain, let's take the washing in*"?

[This website](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-opposite-of-hanging-up-washings-washing.1791739/) says most people say: **bring the washing in**

However, [**bring** shows movement toward the speaker, but **take** shows
movement away from the speaker.](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/confusing_words_bring_take.html)

Eg, *Please take the baby from her bed and bring her to me.*

So, say "**bring or take the washing in**", some may say "**get the washing in**" then we don't worry about **bring or take**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The correct usage of bring vs. take](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111272/the-correct-usage-of-bring-vs-take) Also [Are the verbs Take and Bring considered antonyms?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229558/are-the-verbs-take-and-bring-considered-antonyms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the house, looking at the washing line, you are **going to (the line to) bring the washing** back into the house.

If you are at the line, you are **going to take** the washing from the line back to the house.

Here, the **bring** and **take** relate to the house, not to the person who is fetching / bringing / getting / taking in the washing.

The other consideration is that expressions such as **we need to take the washing in** are often used in the own right rather than with reference to the person or place involved.